# Cast Iron waste pipe can’t be cut

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

We’re replacing a rotten flange from a cast iron pipe and are not able to cut the pipe. We need only to replace the flange connected to the top of the pipe that connects to wax ring on toilet but are having a hard time finding solutions that do not require cutting the old pipe. I would post a pic but right now our new toilet with only the wax ring is sitting on top of the pipe. We know that we need to clean off the old/new wax ring, of course, but where do we find a replaceable flange that connects directly to the top of the cast iron pipe?

Comment: Can you clarify if your actual problem is that you are unable to cut the pipe (why?), or that you are unwilling to cut the pipe (also why?). Your question seem to flip between them and the solutions would be different.

Comment: If your question is where to buy something, that is off-topic here (and most other SE sites). Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Closet ring repair kit would go over top the old rotten one and screw into the floor.